# What does $U(e^{j \lambda})$ mean?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation, signal-processing

I am reading [*“Signal processing for communications”* by Paolo Prandoni and Martin Vetterli](https://www.sp4comm.org/getit.html). In the section *4.4 The DTFT (Discrete-Time Fourier Transform)* (p. 72 of 2008 ed.) they write:

> The somewhat odd notation $X (e ^{j \omega}) $ is quite standard in the signal
> processing literature and offers several advantages:
> <...>
> regardless of context, it immediately identifies a function as the
> Fourier transform of a discrete-time sequence: **for example $U(e^{j \lambda})$
> is just as readily recognizable** ...

**My question:** what $U(e^{j \lambda})$ is?

Because I can’t “readily recognize” it. And authors don't use it anywhere else in the text.

I suspect, that it is a common notation in English, related to complex numbers in general. But I had education in different language and didn’t have enough exposure to math in English. Or I simply don’t know. And, unfortunately, it is hard to create a relevant google search.

Comment: Not really enough context here to be able to answer a notation question, especially if you're not an expert in signal processing literature, but it's probably exactly the same as $X(e^{j\omega})$ with $\omega$ replaced by $\lambda$.

Comment: @Ian Unfortunately, there is no actual additional context to $U(e^{j \lambda})$ in the text (I will clarify it in the question). That is why my guess is that it is related to complex numbers in general, and not to signal processing.

Comment: @Ian However, now I can see, that indeed, they may have shown $U(e^{j \lambda})$ as an equally recognizable alternative to $X (e ^{j \omega}) $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they mean is just that $U(e^{j\lambda})$ is recognizable as a DTFT of some sequence $u[n]$, no matter what names one chooses for the function and for the frequency variable. I agree that they could have made their point a bit clearer.